# (Jetpack Compose) -> Loading State is not working correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to show a loading spinner, but loading state is always showing a false value on a compose function.

I've created a custom spinner, but it not shows

```
@Composable
private fun MainContent(viewModel: SearchJourneyViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val state = viewModel.state
    
    Loader(isDialogVisible = state.isLoading)
}
```

In viewModel loading state is refreshing and returning a value that I need:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SearchJourneyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val cityRepository: CityListRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    var state by mutableStateOf(SearchJourneyState().mock())
        private set

    init {
        loadCityList()
    }

 private fun loadCityList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            cityRepository
                .getCityList()
                .collect { result ->
                    when (result) {
                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            state = 
                                state.copy(
                                    fromCity = //result,
                                    toCity = //result,
                                    isLoading = false,
                                    error = null
                                )
                            } 
                        }

                        is Resource.Error -> {
                            state = 
                                state.copy(
                                    fromCity = null,
                                    toCity = null,
                                    isLoading = false,
                                    error = result.message
                            )
                        }

                        is Resource.Loading -> {
                            state =
                                state.copy(isLoading = result.isLoading)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my state:

```
data class SearchJourneyState(
    val cityList: List<City>? = null,
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val isCityLoading: Boolean = false,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue seems to be the way you are collecting your state.

Try define it as a `StateFlow`:

```
val viewStateFlow: StateFlow<VS> = MutableStateFlow()
```

And then simply collect it your UI layer:

```
val viewState by viewModel.viewStateFlow.collectAsState()
```

Then you should be able loading changes in UI :)